# Linq OrderBy string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of objects that I want to sort alphabetically by their name property.
I have tried the following:

```
List<Item> itemsToSort = dataProvider.Items.ToList();
List<Item> sortedItems = itemsToSort.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

Which doesnt work. The items are still listed in the same way as before and not alphabetically.

EDIT

Here is a more complete sample:

Class:

```
public class MeasureStation
{
    #region Properties

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _measureStation.ID; }
        set { _measureStation.ID = value; }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Navn skal udfyldes")]
    public String Name
    {
        get { return _measureStation.Name; }
        set { _measureStation.Name = value; }
    }

    public DateTime? DateEstablished
    {
        get { return _measureStation.DateEstablished; }
        set { _measureStation.DateEstablished = value; }
    }

    public DateTime? OperationPeriodStart
    {
        get { return _measureStation.OperationPeriodStart; }
        set { _measureStation.OperationPeriodStart = value; }
    }
    .
    .
    and so on...
}
```

The query is:

```
measureStations = dataProvider.MeasureStations.ToList();
var orderedMeasureStations = measureStations.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

When taking a look at the orderedMeasureStations query result, it looks like the following:
entry starting with:

```
F...
S...
a...
L...
```

So it is obviously not sorting by name.

Comment: Are you sure? This should work IMO, show your full code.. Are you sure `Name` is `string`?

Comment: Are you sure they aren't in the right order???

Comment: Agreed, this should work...

Comment: Yeah, it should work, unless Name isn't a string.

Comment: What "doesnt work"? What are the items (`item.Name`s) in `itemsToSort` and `sortedItems`?

Comment: Example data please, since, as noted, this will doubtlessly work.

Comment: You may inadvertantly be binding your front-end controls to itemsToSort instead of sortedItems.

Comment: _measureStation is private property of MeasureStation ? oO

Comment: `'F'<'a'==true` Perhaps you're looking for a case-insensitive sort?

Comment: @spender I've just added another entry starting with a capital L. That gets positioned as last entry in the query

Comment: @xaruth yes _measureStation is a private property of MeasureStation. Without seeing the whole project I understand that it can seem a bit weird, but there are a reason to it. The query is getting items from the database which are then extended in the MeasureStation class. The above sample is just used to give an idea of how the class looks, the actual query and orderby are used directly on the edmx objects before being injected into the constructor of the Measurestation Class. I have checked the database and edmx and the name property is also a string in both of those places.

Comment: Is `orderedMeasureStations` in the same original order as `measureStations` or a different one? That is, does it actually sort somehow or it just doesn't do anything. In any case...show us some sample data...

Answer (score 2):

I do not see how your  `class MeasureStation` will ever work

What is `_measureStation`, is it `this`?

If it is, Then it should look like, note that the property cannot have the same name as its respective private member

```
  public class MeasureStation
  {
    private int id;//private is optional as it is default
    public int ID
    {
      get { return this.id; }
      set { this.id = value; }
    }
    private String name;//private is optional as it is default
    public String Name
    {
      get { return this.name; }
      set { this.name = value; }
    }
  }
```

Though, it is equivalent to the class with auto-properties:

```
public class MeasureStation
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public String Name {get;set;}
}
```

So, I run against both of them

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  List<MeasureStation> itemsToSort
    = new List<MeasureStation>()
        {
          new MeasureStation() {ID = 01, Name = "Bbbb"},
          new MeasureStation() {ID = 01, Name = "Aaaa"},
          new MeasureStation() {ID = 01, Name = "Cccc"}
        };
  List<MeasureStation> sortedItems = itemsToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

  Console.WriteLine("******itemsToSort*****");
  foreach (var item in itemsToSort)
      Console.WriteLine(item.Name.ToString());

  Console.WriteLine("******sortedItems*****");
  foreach (var item in sortedItems)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name.ToString());

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

having gotten ordered output:

```
******itemsToSort*****
Bbbb
Aaaa
Cccc
******sortedItems*****
Aaaa
Bbbb
Cccc
```